# Swift Error "static member cannot be used on instance of type"

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I want to overload the operator for my struct but I get the message "static member 'rating' cannot be used on instance of type 'GlobalSettings'".
I already read couple answers to this error but the solutions there don't help me at all. How can I solve this problem?

```
struct GlobalSettings{
    static var rating = false
}

func ==(l: GlobalSettings, r: GlobalSettings) -> Bool {
    if l.rating == r.rating {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: `l` and `r` don't have a `rating` variable. `GlobalSettings` does.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to remove the "static". *Why* do you think that `rating` should be a static property?

Comment: And btw, simplify the function body to `return l.rating == r.rating`

Comment: I use the GlobalSettings to keep all settings in my app so they can be accessed anywhere. I believe static variables are good for that but I am a Swift newbie so I am not sure

Comment: Then why do you define == to compare two "global settings", if there are no instances of that type?

Comment: My idea was to create a "copy" of all variables inside GlobalSettings structure during launching every View Controller and then whenever the VC appears again it checks if the settings where changed, if so then it would refresh some UI elements. I guess I can do it with delegates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Static members can not be accessed with Instance variables like `l` and `r`.

Static members must be accessed through the type (`class`/`struct`/`enum`) name like:

```
GlobalSettings.rating
```