# open sms app with text and url in swift by using MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: swift, text, sms, openurl

Hi I want to open sms app with teat along url I write following code but I facing

error like:Static member 'canSendText' cannot be used on instance of type 'MFMessageComposeViewController'

```
var controller1 = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if indexPath.section == 0
            {
                if (controller1.canSendText()) {

                    let urlToShare = "http://www.appzoy.com"

                    controller1.body = "Hey I just gave an Awesome Assessment on UAssess App you can also try it. I scored , Try to beat my score \(urlToShare)"

                    controller1.messageComposeDelegate = self as? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
                    self.present(controller1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Just follow the white rabbit and use it statically: `MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Error "static member cannot be used on instance of type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475097/swift-error-static-member-cannot-be-used-on-instance-of-type)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned into [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller) you should use:

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
    print("SMS services are available")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
//MARK:- Send Mail
//MARK:-

func sendMail(emailTitle : String , messageBody : String , toRecipents : [String]){

    if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {

        let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        let emailTitle = emailTitle //Feedback
        let messageBody = messageBody //"Feature request or bug report?"
        let toRecipents = toRecipents //["friend@stackoverflow.com"]
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
        self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{
        //Show alert
    }
}
```

**The call sendMail function**

```
let urlToShare = "http://www.appzoy.com"
        self.sendMail(emailTitle: "Title of Mail", messageBody: "Hey I just gave an Awesome Assessment on UAssess App you can also try it. I scored , Try to beat my score \(urlToShare)", toRecipents: ["abc@mail.com", "def@mail.com"])
```